# When you should implement Runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was reading some articles on topic **"implement runnable vs extend thread"** and I do understand that implementing runnable is prefered because in Java you can't have multiple inheritance. I also read some article that said when you use `run()` method it just executes the code in current thread, and when you use `start()` it creates new thread which is I think better, but it depends. But I am still confused about, why you should implement Runnable in class? Why is that needed? Or extending Thread? You can create anonymous thread and start it without implementing runnable or anything.

> Sample code of anonymous thread without implementing or extending

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.print("Example");
    }
}.start();
```

**EDIT**: After some answers and comments, I think what I did not understand was bit more clarified. I actually did not know the reason of implementing Runnable if its run method does not create new Thread. But many of you told me you can use something like this

> new Thread(new Runnable())

So finally I want to know - This code up here, does it create a new Thread and executes the code inside the run method ?

Comment: Depends on what APIs you need overridden.

Comment: In most serious cases, you don't directly use threads. you use executors with pools.

Comment: Thread#run executes the Runnable's run method within the current thread context. No new thread is created. Thread#start creates a new thread which will then call the threads run method within the context of the newly create "native" thread...

Comment: pretty much `always` implement `Runnable` or `Callable` you should never in *normal* cases need to sub-class `Thread` directly, if you do, you either know what you are doing and why for a good reason, or you are in way over your head. For advanced cases you should be using `Executors` and the plumbing around them instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Jon Skeet's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/541506/18573) almost five years ago still seems relevant.

Comment: You are extending Thread in that sample code. You are making a [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) which extends Thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["implements Runnable" vs. "extends Thread"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread)

Comment: @LouisWasserman It is not duplicate because I know some pros and cons of both ( of course I am not a pro) but I was asking what is the use of Runnable if it does not create new Thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why you should implement Runnable in class?

The only way to implement any interface is to define a class.  Here are [docs on Java interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

> Why is that needed? Or extending Thread?

You need to do one or the other if you want to use `Thread` directly.  As others have pointed out, you should take a look at the `ExecutorService` classes which provide thread-pool support and hide the `Thread` stuff from the user.  Here's the [tutorial on the subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).

> You can create anonymous thread and start it without implementing runnable or anything.

Your code is an anonymous class that extends `Thread`.  As Ishtar provides, here are the [docs about anonymous classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) in case there is a question.  If you looked at the `.class` files generated by the Java compiler from your code sample you would see something like `Main.class` and `Main$1.class`.  Java is actually creating a class for you on the fly.

You could also so an anonymous class which `implements Runnable`:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      System.out.print("Example");
   }
}).start();
```

But whether or not your use an anonymous class is orthogonal to the question of whether implementing `Runnable` or extending `Thread` is the better mechanism to define your thread task.  For that question, as @MiserableVariable points out, [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/541506/18573) is still very relevant.

Comment: Haha, very literal answer.

Comment: Well, actually I just wanted to know, when to implement Runnable on some class, if you can just simply use anonymous Thread. That was because of the article I read. It said that by implementin Runnable you use run method which does not create new Thread so I was unsure what is use of it then. But now I see you can do Something like you did In the code (Passing new Runnable to Thread). This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

#### Runnable or Callable is the preferred idiom

Pretty much `always` implement `Runnable` or `Callable` you should never in *normal* cases need to sub-class `Thread` directly.

If you do need specialized behavior of the `Thread` class, you either know what you are doing and why you need a different behavior for the `Thread` class for a good reason, or you are in way over your head.

#### Executors are the way to go

For most cases you should be using `Executors` and the plumbing around them instead of rolling your own when dealing with multiple `Threads` and their interactions and management.

You should never create a new `Thread` and manage its life-cycle anymore, error prone and hard to manage, lean on the `Executors` and leverage them.

Answer (score 1):

When you deal with your own class hierarchy, you don't want to start from the `Thread` class in the first place. `Thread` class is an infrastructure for running your `Runnable`s. And there is more, e.g. `Executor`, etc. `Thread` holds its state specific to its API. `Runnable` is a convenient (and a proper) way of wrapping your processing logic and isolate it from the surrounding it should be executed in.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your requirements, but in general it is a good idea to seperate *What should be done?* from *Who does it?*.

A `Thread` can execute code, but it has a lifecycle and once it finished you can't start the same `Thread` instance again.

A `Runnable` is just some code that can be executed or `run()`. The lifecycle of the object that implements `Runnable` is not necessarily bound to a thread's lifecycle and this gives you great benefit:

- The same `Runnable` instance can be run multiple times. If you want to re-run a `Runnable` just create a `Thread`, pass the `Runnable` into the thread's constructor and call `start()`.
- Since a `Runnable` instance can be re-run easily the instance can remember the previous run's state.
- The same `Runnable` instance can be run by multiple threads in parallel.

Comment: The same `Runnable` **can** also be ran in parallel.

Comment: Great answer too, it is a shame that I can not accept your answer too

Answer (score 0):

When you call `run()` method, it is method invocation on same thread rather than new thread. If you want something happen on separate thread, you either need to `extend Thread` (or) `implement Runnable` and call `start()` on thread object. [Java thread life cycle](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm) may give you some clarity on difference between calling run() and start()

Comment: Is this possible: `new Thread(new MyObject()).start();` if MyObject implements Runnable?

Comment: @dani-h: this should help you:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Answer (score -1):

Anonymous classes are useful, but not applicable in most scenarios. This is as true for a `Thread` class, as for any other type of class.

In cases, for instance, that multiple instantiations of a Thread object are needed and that Thread object also has state (e.g., some calculation results), or communicates with other objects (e.g., via a queue), one has to extend the `Thread` class, or implementing the `Runnable` interface and then using a `Thread` constructor to actually start the thread.

The subject has been discussed extensively, so you can check the answers (and the links) posted to an [earlier StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471432/why-implements-runnable-is-preferred-over-extends-thread), or many other similar ones.

Answer (score -1):

Quoting from the Oracle documentation on Concurrency.

> The first idiom, which employs a Runnable object, is more general,
>   because the Runnable object can subclass a class other than Thread.
>   The second idiom is easier to use in simple applications, but is
>   limited by the fact that your task class must be a descendant of
>   Thread. This lesson focuses on the first approach, which separates the
>   Runnable task from the Thread object that executes the task. Not only
>   is this approach more flexible, but it is applicable to the high-level
>   thread management APIs covered later.

Note that the first idiom is Runnable and the second is extending from Thread. It looks like **flexibility** is the main motivator to go for implementing **Runnable** approach over extending **Thread**. I highly doubt if they both map to different implementations by the JVM (although I can't confirm it).

Comment: _I highly doubt if they both map to different implementations by the JVM_ What are you referring to? `Runnable` and `Thread`? Of course they are different.

Comment: I was referring to thread-management by the JVM... Like PC Register creation, JVM Stack Creation,etc.... (I mean runtime data areas)

Comment: You should probably rephrase your answer. The term _they_ currently seems to be referring to the `Runnable` and `Thread`.

Comment: Perhaps I should, I was referring to bytecode - to - threading translation by the JVM. Being a novice student of JVM, I can't say this  with authority but it looks like all threads are created and managed exactly the same way by JVM regardless of how they are specified in the Java Language...